# How to get an approximate solution to get a shortest path going through all the nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, path, shortest-path

Does someone know an algorithm or something to do that

So I have nodes connected with arc's and I have to find an solution to find an approximate shortest path that covers all the nodes. (I can only visit them once)

It must be an approximative path because it will take to much time to get The shortest path

Thanks for your answers :)

(I have to do that in java)

Comment: This is known as the [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: @JanDvorak - It might actually be the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem); he never says he needs to get back to the original node.

Comment: These kind of problems are collectively known as _Graph Theory_ and there is a large number of problems, this included, with Well known solutions.  Has this been introduced to you?

Answer (score 5):

This is known as the [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and a reasonable and fast approximation is to always visit the closest unvisited node next, then retry the same with several other starting locations. Normally, this gets you very close to the optimal solution.

Another algorithm is to first construct a minimum spanning tree of the graph and then delete repeated nodes. This guarantees a certain upper bound on sub-optimality (no more than twice as long in the euclidean case, ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Constructive_heuristics)))

Yet another algorithm is to start with the first three nodes, then add the next nodes in some order (initial, sorted by x-coordinate, sorted by distance from center...) by splitting existing edges (or adding new ones at the end, in case of shortest path) while keeping the path as short as possible.

Once you have a solution (even a bad one), you can improve it by K-opt: repeatedly pick K random edges, remove them entirely and find the best way to reconnect the new endpoints. A variant of K-opt is the [Lin-Kerningham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin%E2%80%93Kernighan) heuristic that alternates 2-opt steps with 3-opt steps (in some order) where two of the three edges are always adjanced.

If most of the edges are missing or very long (the distaces between two nodes don't form a metric) then you have a problem. Let's just say it's NP-complete do decide if such a path even exists if there are missing edges.

Answer (score 1):

A very fast approximation is to order the vertexes along a space filling curve. A space filling curve reduces the dimension and also preserve some spatial information. Try the moore curve for the travel salesman problem because it's a copy of 4 hilbert curves such that the start and end points are next to each other. But it's a bit more expensive to draw.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1. Not sure it's actually faster than closest-first, though.

Comment: Update some example of tsp with a hilbert curve. The green shape is basically a tsp.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm? I always confusing this with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem. Isn't this expensivier?

Comment: You're right - I meant the nearest neighbour algorithm. I've also realised it's not actually very fast (so hilbert's curve wins. I think I can't get nearest neighbour below quadratic.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The method is called 'genetic optimization' and goes as follows
1. Find a solution, i.e.  path which visits each node once.
2. Select k adjacent nodes randomly: N1,N2..Nk : X->N1->..Nk->Y
3. Check to see if there are shorter paths from X to Y using the Nodes N1..Nk
4. replace the path X -*> Y by the shorter solution
5. goto 2

k must be small (5 or less) so that you can easily find a shorter combination

The nice thing about it is that you can stop at any time and use the existing solution.  An improvement would be to randomly select a larger k once.

Comment: How is that related to genetics? What you are describing is K-opt (which is not a bad algorithm per se)

Comment: or a bad version thereof. If you always pick K _adjanced_ nodes, then you can't do much optimisation

Comment: I know this solution from delphi. The author called it 'optimization using genetic algorithm'. If I google it, I find this type of solution. If you refer to it as 'K-opt' (or it's even the only legal official name) good. Then I learned something new.

Comment: To call it a "genetic algorithm", you need to have several candidate solutions, combine the good ones and discard the bad ones. Perhaps what you describe is meant as a tiny cogwheel in a bigger scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to implement the algorithm yourself, you may want to look at [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/).  It has an implementation of an algorithm to find [Hamiltonian Cycles](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/HamiltonianCycle.html).

Comment: Too bad this answer will be useless when the link goes dead. Link-only answers should be comments.